# Why dlmwrite eliminate colnames of matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Im' new in Matlab. I have double matrix M like this:

```
 3.4452e-10       3.727e-10
 5.3276e-11      5.4956e-11
-4.5277e-12     -1.5932e-10
 9.5572e-11     -2.9293e-11
 4.8192e-11     -7.5237e-11
-1.0847e-10      3.5613e-11
```

and gave name columane name for data as follow

```
 dataset({M, 'A','B'})
then I write it to folder using 
 dlmwrite('MyNewfile',M)
```

but when I open the MyNewfile, I see that the column names of the matrix is eliminated.
Does anyone knows how can I keep column names when I write it in directory?

Answer (score 1):

First, `dataset` is deprecated, you should use `table` instead.

Second, from Matlab documentation:

> dlmwrite(filename,M) writes **numeric** data in array M to an ASCII format
>   file

So it will only write the contents of your matrices but not any non-numeric data.

You can always use write first the column headers in the file and then append your data, or use another matlab writing function that handles text  and numeric data

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider you are trying to write A to a file there are two methods

```
A =

   1.0e-09 *

    0.3445    0.3727
    0.0533    0.0550
   -0.0045   -0.1593
    0.0956   -0.0293
    0.0482   -0.0752
   -0.1085    0.0356
```

either you append the row names with in a file like this

```
>> dlmwrite('testtext3.txt',['A             B'] ,'delimiter','')
>> dlmwrite('testtext3.txt',[A],'-append','delimiter','\t','roffset',1)
```

or You convert A into a table

```
T =array2table(A,'VariableNames',{'A' ,'B'})

T = 

         A              B     
    ___________    ___________

     3.4452e-10      3.727e-10
     5.3276e-11     5.4956e-11
    -4.5277e-12    -1.5932e-10
     9.5572e-11    -2.9293e-11
     4.8192e-11    -7.5237e-11
    -1.0847e-10     3.5613e-11
```

and then write this table to a file

```
writetable(T,'testing.txt')
```

**UPDATE :** As a user has raised a question of parsing the data given below is a method

```
fileID = fopen('testtext3.txt','r+');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s%s')
C = 

    {7x1 cell}    {7x1 cell}

>> C{1}

ans = 

    'A'
    '3.4452e-10'
    '5.3276e-11'
    '-4.5277e-12'
    '9.5572e-11'
    '4.8192e-11'
    '-1.0847e-10'
```

Comment: I am suggesting both the methods and actually telling how to use them the OP can choose any of them which is somehow very clear from my post

Comment: Your method: 1) Uses different delimiters for the header and for the data. 2) You are appending data and using a row offset of 1, which will leave a blank line between headers and data. But fine. Next question will be how to parse the generated file.

Comment: what has using different delimiters has to do with reading the data ? read the  updated answer

Comment: How else would you read a numeric data with the string on the top ? store the data into a matrix with a string ? the whole proces which you defind can be done by just `str2double(C{1}(2:end))` please try using dlmread to read the data from a text file whihc has been stored as table you will get your answer

Comment: Ofcourse `str2double(C{1:2}(2:end))` wont work , thats something already defined by MATLAB but `str2double(C{1}(2:end))` would, please parse a table by using `dlmread` !

Comment: Function readtable. You can even specify the format of each column, and of course will output the contents in a table structure, which is efficient and full of matlab pre-build functions http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html